# Any reason ReSharper will not work when viewing SQL files in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-6.1

I have ReSharper 6.1 installed and I use it with Visual Studio 2010. ReSharper works perfectly fine, except when I open an .sql file.

When an SQL file is the active window my ReSharper shortcuts stop working. I don't mind if intellisense doesn't work with SQL, but even <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (open file, open type) isn't working.

Makes switching between files a little bit more inconvenient.

Is there an option that is disabling ReSharper shortcuts in sql files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that commands from a context other than *Global* or *Text Editor* take precedence when you open a SQL file?

If you go to *Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard*, there's a command called *Data.SqlEditorResultsAsFile* that is bound to *Ctrl+Shift+T* in *Transact-SQL Editor* context. Try removing this assignment - could this help control back to ReSharper's *Go to Type* that uses *Ctrl+Shift+T* in *Global* and *Text Editor* contexts?

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks.